# how can I change kiwi template text on test case?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I would like to ask if it is possible to edit the predefined text when creating a new test case? See. attachment.

Thanks, 
Tomas[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it is not possible to do this. Please file a RFE on GitHub so we can track this feature. We've got an idea to make it possible to select a TestCase/TestPlan as a template which can solve this request as well as a few other issues that we have open.